# How to track internet usage (upload & download) on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth

I use a broadband modem to connect to internet on my linux machine. I've used the `gnome-system-monitor` app that correctly displays the kbps as well as total bytes consumed in each session. Now, is there any easy way in linux for me to log all these consumptions (downloads and uploads)?

The thing is that I use a limited usage plan (n number of GBs each month), hence I want to keep track of my usage. What is the best approach to do this on linux?

Comment: Very similar, bordering on duplicate: [Is there any way to see how much data I sent via Internet? at Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80717/2465)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Install `vnstat`, it gives logs the usage on a network interface and you can display the usage over different time periods.

Here's the default output from my system

```
                  rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
eth0:
   Jun '13     14.40 GiB  /    1.70 GiB  /   16.10 GiB
   Jul '13      3.57 GiB  /    2.55 GiB  /    6.12 GiB  /   40.44 GiB
 yesterday    968.58 MiB  /    2.26 GiB  /    3.21 GiB
     today    377.88 MiB  /   26.73 MiB  /  404.61 MiB  /     582 MiB
```

If you get `vnstati` as well, you can display the data in different ways e.g.

[image: Usage graph]

Comment: Which command did you use to get this nice image? When I use `vnstati -d` it only says `At least output mode and file parameter needs to be given.`

Comment: The image shows a vertical summary (-vs option) and you need an output file (-o option), so the command to output the above image to foo.png is 'vnstati -vs -o foo.png'

Comment: Thank you. And what is rx and TX?

Comment: Rx - receive Tx transmit

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you think about adding this to your answer? So how you find what your wlan interface is and `vnstati -vs -i wlp3s0 -o ~/summary.png`

Comment: ifconfig will show you your networks

Comment: @parkydr is there any way to view past details from vnstat (before it was installed)?

Comment: No, vnstat does the usage logging

Answer (score 5):

Easiest to use and easiest to control output and redirect to file for continuous logging:

```
ifstat
```

Probably comes with most linux distributions, and can be installed with brew on mac. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 4):

`vnstat` is probably the best way to do this. It can be installed using the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

If you don't want to keep checking the data usage status every time then use:

```
watch -n 5 --differences vnstat -d eth0
```

It would display the status every 5 seconds in the open terminal with the differences that occur in the values. `-d` is used to display the status of each day and `eth0` is the ethernet used for internet connection (`wlan0` may be used for WiFi).